# How to start and keep sockets connections accross multiple activities?

Tags: android, sockets, android-service

i'm having trouble finding a way to implement this:

I have an activity A from where i'll start 2x separate socket connections.
Afterwards i'll move to an activity B from where i'll go back and fourth with activities C and D. All 3 activities will exchange messages via the sockets.

Now from my understanding i need to create a service for each socket, but how exactly do i maintain both sockets open, without creating a new connection everytime i switch to another activity?

Also how do i keep the services running an "accept loop", prompting an action for the current activity the user is in?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that you should use a `Service`.  A good rule of thumb is that you should use a service for any background processing that is not logically bound by the lifecycle of a single activity.  (And use `AsyncTask` for background processing that *is* logically bound by the lifecycle of a single activity.)

But you don't need to create a service for each socket.  You should create one service that does whatever it is you need to do with the sockets.  There are a variety of ways your activities can interact with the service and pass messages or obtain references to its sockets, which you can read about in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).